# Distributing n items among m spaces where m can exceed n

Tags: combinatorics

Lets say I have n processes and m time slots. For each time slot I want to allocate some process. I don't need to use all n processes, but I do need to fill all m buckets. The catch is that I can't repeat the same process in 2 consecutive spaces. ex) n=2, m=3

ABA and BAB (where A and B represent processes) are valid combinations
AAB or BBA is not because AA has 2 consecutive repeating elements.

Another example n=3,m=2. Answer=6

AB,AC,BA,BC,CA,CB

How would I calculate the number of ways I can allocate these n processes to m time slots?

I thought about this at first as a simple math problem and may still be. I was initially thinking just multiply n*n-1*n*n-1... m times. but I thought of counter examples to this. I thought of the example n=2 and m=4. In this case the valid options are

ABAB
BABA

So the answer is 2. But the above method would produce 4.

So how can I properly count these?

Btw this is not homework, i saw this problem in a community forum i'm part of and found it interesting.

Comment: There are $n$ choices for the first slot, $n-1$ for each of the subsequent slots, so...

Comment: For your $n=2,m=4$ example, $n\times (n-1)^{m-1}$ correctly gives $2\times 1^3=2$.

Comment: @lulu there are n choices for the first slot, n-1 for the 2nd, but n choices for the 3rd. You can repeat elements, it's just that no 2 consecutive slots can have the same element.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  After the first slot, there are $n-1$ choices for each other slot.  You have to subtract $1$ because you can't use whatever you used for the prior slot.

Comment: Think about the case $n=2$, for arbitrary $m$.  Once you make the choice for the first slot, you are done.  The rest of the sequence is forced on you. 1 choice for each  of the other slots.

Comment: Actually you are right about that, my mistake. That formula could be the answer